# Resistor That is neither Series or Parallel

Tags: resistance, power-engineering

[image]

My textbook says that the 5Ω and 2Ω resistor are neither in series or parallel. My understanding of the reasoning is that the current from the 5Ω resistor has two pathways it can travel - either to the 2 ohm resistor, or into node b, thus, it cannot be series. It also is not parallel, since it does not share two nodes with the two ohm resistor, so it is neither.

[image]
However, in this example, from 'The Organic Chemistry Tutor's video, he treats the 12Ω resistor as in series with the 8Ω resistor, whereas current can go into the open circuit region, or the 8Ω resistor region, thus, it cant be in series.

Can someone explain why he treats the 12Ω resistor as in series, and clarify details of when  branches can be neither in series or parallel.

Comment: Current requires a closed loop to flow, so you statement that current can go into the open circuit is incorrect

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: When the superposition theorem is used for analyzing the circuit , both resistors 2 Ohm and 5 Ohm are to be considered in parallel for the voltage source set to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whereas current can go into the open circuit region, or the 8Ω resistor region

Wrong. Current can't flow through the open region.

Two key info:

- A current coming to paralleled resistors will be shared by the resistors according to their resistances: Higher resistance will take lower portion and vice versa. For example, if a current of 10 Amps is coming towards paralleled 4 Ohms and 1 Ohm resistors then 8 Amps will flow through 1 Ohm and 2 Amps will flow through 4 Ohms. (8 A x 1 Ohms = 2 A x 4 Ohms)
- Open circuit is considered as infinity (infinite Ohms), and short circuit is considered as zero (Ohms).

Now the open port in parallel with the right-most 8 Ohm resistor can be thought of infinite resistance. So the open port will take zero current (because its resistance is infinity) therefore the current flowing from A to B will not be divided i.e. all of the current will flow through 8 Ohms. This makes the current flowing through 12 Ohms (A to B) equal to the current flowing through B to ground, which leads to a conclusion of that 12 Ohms and 8 Ohms are in series.

If you look at the 2 Ohm and 3 Ohm resistors in the first circuit, you'll see that the current coming from a to b (flowing through 5 Ohm) will be divided into the 2-Ohm and 3-Ohm resistors and the current flowing through 2 Ohms will be 1.5 times the one flowing through 3 Ohms.

---

Another way to see why an open circuit takes zero current is by looking at the equivalent resistance of paralleled resistors. Since the parallel equivalent of two resistors equals to the ratio of multiplication of them to the sum of them, an open port in parallel with a non-zero resistance will not change the equivalent.